# Will MQSC define queue command ever delete or corrupt messages?

Tags: websphere, message-queue, ibm-mq

In WebSphere MQ 6, I want to script the creation of new queues. However the queues may already exist, and I need the script to be idempotent.

I can create queues using the commands [documented here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv6/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mq.csqzaj.doc/sc11190_.htm). For example:

```
DEFINE QREMOTE(%s) RNAME(%s) RQMNAME(%s) XMITQ(%s) DEFPSIST(YES) REPLACE
```

or

```
DEFINE QLOCAL(%s) DESCR(%s) DEFPSIST(YES) REPLACE
```

The `REPLACE` keyword ensures that creation does not fail if the queue already exists.

I've tested this with an existing, non-empty queue and it seems that no messages were lost. However this is not proof enough. I need to be certain that no messages will ever be lost or corrupted if I run a `DEFINE Q... REPLACE` command against an existing queue. The existing queue might even be participating in transactions at the time.

Can anyone confirm or deny this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `DEFINE` command with `REPLACE` fails if the object is open.  Therefore you cannot redefine a queue with pending transactions.  The [manual states](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzaj.doc/sc11240_.htm) that all messages in the queue are retained during a `DEFINE` with `REPLACE`, and this implies no loss of message integrity.  You can `ALTER` a queue with `FORCE` option to change a queue that is currently open as described [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzaj.doc/sc11240_1.htm).  That too retains messages in the queue without loss of integrity.

The `DEFINE` command will not affect the messages in a queue.  The only effects you might notice are, for example, if you change the queue from `FIFO` to `PRIORITY` or vice versa.  This only changes the indexing and ordering for *new* messages in the queue and does not affect existing messages.  Similarly, changing attributes of the queue that affect handles only take effect the next time the queue is opened.  An example of that is changing `BIND(ONOPEN)` to `BIND(NOTFIXED)`.

One of the things that I have been [recommending for a while](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0811_mismes/0811_mismes.html) for WMQ clusters is to split the queue definition up into build-time and run-time attributes.  For example:

```
DEFINE QLOCAL (APP.FUNCTION.SUBFUNCTION.QA) +
       GET(DISABLED) +
       PUT(DISABLED) +
       NOTRIGGER +
       NOREPLACE
ALTER  QLOCAL (APP.FUNCTION.SUBFUNCTION.QA) +
       DESCR('APP service queue for QA') +
       DEFPSIST(NO) +
       BOTHRESH(5) +
       BOQNAME('APP.FUNCTION.BACKOUT.QA') +
       CLUSTER('DIV_QA') +
       CLUSNL(' ') +
       DEFBIND(NOTFIXED)
```

In this case the `GET`, `PUT` and `TRIGGER` attributes are considered run-time and are only set when the queue is first defined.  This allows you to define a new queue in the cluster and have it be disabled until you are ready to turn on the app.  In subsequent runs of the script, these attributes are never changed because the statement uses `NOREPLACE`.  So once you enable `GET` and `PUT` on the queue these attributes (and the function of the app) are never disturbed by subsequent script runs.

The `ALTER` then handles all the attributes that are considered build-time.  For example, if you change the description, you want it picked up in the next script run.  Because we defined the queue in the previous step (or that step failed because the queue exists), we know the ALTER will work.

Whether any attribute such as the cluster membership is build-time or run-time is up to you to decide.  This is just an example born from many cases where administrators inadvertently broke something by re-running the MQSC script.

But to answer your question a bit more on point, the things that break are because someone reset a run-time attribute such as `GET(DISABLED)` *(which can cause an in-flight transaction to be backed out if the app tries to perform a GET on that queue after gets are disabled)* and not because the change caused an integrity failure of the queue, a message or a transaction.

Comment: All your MQ questions are belong to us.  :-)